# Check if message contains any of array discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hi I am trying to check whether the message contains a value of my array but i can not quite figure out how to. Here is my code

```
if(current_turn == 1 || current_turn == 2) {
  var valid_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  if(message.content.includes(valid_numbers)){

  }
}
```

Comment: `valid_numbers.includes(message.content)`

Comment: `let numsInMsg = valid_numbers.find(num => message.content.includes(num))`
then check if numsInMsg has any elements

Comment: Try this : `valid_numbers.some((x) => message.content.includes(x))`. message.content is an array right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking here at `Array.prototype.some()`.
In short, `.some()` is an iterator that goes over each of the values found inside of an array and returns a boolean value depending on whether one of the elements matches a certain condition.

Seeing as we want to check whether one of the values inside of your array are found inside of the message's content, we can use `.some()` to determine if the content **includes** one of the elements:

```js
let valid_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
console.log(valid_numbers.some(element => message.content.includes(element))
// message content = 'I have 9 bears' - true
// message content = 'I  have 0 candy bars' - false
```